# appsettings.json not reading new ConnectionString .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Unable to read the changed connection string from `appsettings.json` file in .NET Core 3.1.

I have tried changing the name of connection strings but that didn't work.

This is how I am getting the connection string in `CompositionRoot.cs` file:

```
public static void injectDependencies(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductionDb")));
}
```

This is what I have in `appsettings.json`:

[image: Appsettings.json image attached]

Comment: Are you injecting ok the configuration, is configuration setted?

Comment: @krlosmederos yes.

Comment: please paste all code

Comment: @GabrielMartinezBustos Pasted.

Comment: This may be because you also have an `appsettings.Development.json` that overrides these values. Try defining the same pair in the Development file. Or just test if you get that connection string when you run the app on release mode.

Comment: @AnastasiosMoraitis I don't have the connection  string in `appsettings.Development.json` and the order the configurations are read is as follows.

1. `appsettings.json file`
2. `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json file`

Comment: You need to include how you defined your configuration in order to have a [MCVE]. And don't past images of code or configuration: we're software developers, we work with text. We can include text in answers far more easily that way, and it saves bandwidth, and the text can be properly indexed for searching.